# Using variables in the format() function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

Is it possible to use variables in the format specifier in the format()-function in Python? I have the following code, and I need VAR to equal field_size:

```
def pretty_printer(*numbers):
  str_list = [str(num).lstrip('0') for num in numbers]

  field_size = max([len(string) for string in str_list])

  i = 1
  for num in numbers:
    print("Number", i, ":", format(num, 'VAR.2f')) # VAR needs to equal field_size
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use the [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), which lets you interpolate other variables for things like the width:

```
'Number {i}: {num:{field_size}.2f}'.format(i=i, num=num, field_size=field_size)
```

Each `{}` is a placeholder, filling in named values from the keyword arguments (you can use numbered positional arguments too). The part after the optional `:` gives the format (the second argument to the `format()` function, basically), and you can use more `{}` placeholders there to fill in parameters.

Using numbered positions would look like this:

```
'Number {0}: {1:{2}.2f}'.format(i, num, field_size)
```

but you could also mix the two or pick different names:

```
'Number {0}: {1:{width}.2f}'.format(i, num, width=field_size)
```

If you omit the numbers and names, the fields are automatically numbered, so the following is equivalent to the preceding format:

```
'Number {}: {:{width}.2f}'.format(i, num, width=field_size)
```

Note that the whole string is a template, so things like the `Number` string and the colon are part of the template here.

You need to take into account that the field size *includes* the decimal point, however; you may need to adjust your size to add those 3 extra characters.

Demo:

```
>>> i = 3
>>> num = 25
>>> field_size = 7
>>> 'Number {i}: {num:{field_size}.2f}'.format(i=i, num=num, field_size=field_size)
'Number 3:   25.00'
```

Last but not least, of Python 3.6 and up, you can put the variables directly into the string literal by using a [formatted string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498):

```
f'Number {i}: {num:{field_size}.2f}'
```

The advantage of using a regular string template and `str.format()` is that you can swap out the template, the advantage of f-strings is that makes for very readable and compact string formatting inline in the string value syntax itself.

Comment: @MartijnP: Can't python do this?  fmt='10.5f';   print(f'variance = {variance:fmt}')

Comment: @JoonhoPark yes, Python can do that provided you use a nested replacement part: `print(f'variance = {variance:{fmt}}')`. Demo: https://repl.it/repls/CommonBlaringLegacysystem#main.py

Answer (score 7):

I prefer this (new 3.6) style:

```
name = 'Eugene'
f'Hello, {name}!'
```

or a multi-line string:

```
f'''
Hello,
{name}!!!
{a_number_to_format:.1f}
'''
```

which is really handy.

I find the old style formatting sometimes hard to read. Even concatenation could be more readable. See an example:

```
'{} {} {} {} which one is which??? {} {} {}'.format('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7')
```

Comment: @crypdick Yes it does: `{a_number_to_format:.1f}`

Answer (score 0):

I used just assigned the VAR value to field_size and change the print statement. It works.

```
def pretty_printer(*numbers):
  str_list = [str(num).lstrip('0') for num in numbers]

  field_size = max([len(string) for string in str_list])

  VAR=field_size

  i = 1
  for num in numbers:
      print("Number", i, ":", format(num, f'{VAR}.2f'))
```