# I have issues with the object.partition(element_to_search) in python

Tags: python, string, partition

I have a .txt file and I want to search for a particular number in that file and get the following couple of characters.
The number I want to find in the txt file comes from another txt file called "htmlBetId.txt".
I am struggling to make the following code work:

```
RawFile = open("htmlraw2.txt","rt")
searchfile = RawFile.readline()
betFile = open("htmlBetId.txt","rt")
betID = betFile.readline()
betIDTest =str("'"+'"betId":'+betID[:8]+"'")
print(betIDTest)
                
left,sep,right = searchfile.partition(betIDTest)
print(sep)
```

When I run the code I get something like this (because of the print):

```
'"betId":88986745'
```

In this form, it can't find it.

Now if I write this in the previous code:

```
left,sep,right = searchfile.partition('"betId":88986745')
```

It can find it.
The problem is that the number after "betId": changes so I have to make the first code work.

If you want the code and the txt files I can post them if you want.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should consider [opening files using the with keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: Try: `fmt_string = '"betId":{}'; betIDTest = fmt_string.format(betID[:8])`

Comment: Related: [String formatting in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945749/string-formatting-in-python-3), [Using variables in the format() function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413109/using-variables-in-the-format-function-in-python). The documentation: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings)

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52155591/how-to-insert-string-into-a-string-as-a-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52155591/how-to-insert-string-into-a-string-as-a-variable)

Comment: Thank you so much! the fmt_string line worked! Awesome!