# Replace multiple strings with python variable in a sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x, pandas

I have a datetime list lets say **datelist** which I later convert into string.
I want to run following sql query : `select * from test_table_20220401 where date < '2022-04-01 00:00:00' and date1 > '20220401'` for multiple dates. So I need to replace the 'dates' string in the query with python variables from the **datelist** that I have created. I can resolve for this when I have to replace a string from a query with only one python variable. Please refer the below code:

```
for in datelist:
    query = "select * from test_table where date1 > {}".format(i)
```

Please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `date` and `date1` columns have different formats in `test_table`. If that's the case, then you'll need a function to convert the dates in `datelist` to the format required by the sql table.

In order to pass multiple vars into a string, I typically use f-strings.

```
date = '2022-04-01 00:00:00'
date1 = '20220401'

query = f'select * from test_table_20220401 where date < {date} and date1 > {date1}'
```

You can also add multiple variables with .format(). An answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413109/using-variables-in-the-format-function-in-python) explains. Documentation for string formatting styles and .format() function specifically is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html).