# SQL in python to include a where clause

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, prepared-statement

Here are the SQL code as string in python:

```
sql_code="""
SELECT VAR
    VAR2
FROM TABLE
WHERE VAR in ('A','B')
"""
```

And I would like to create a variable for the list of selection in the WHERE clause, this is what we can do:

```
sql_code_arg1="""
SELECT VAR
VAR2
FROM TABLE
WHERE VAR in {}
"""
```

Then

```
lst=["A","B"]
print(sql_code_arg1.format(tuple(lst)))
```

Now, I would like to parameter the entire condition in WHERE clause:

```
sql_code_arg2="""
SELECT VAR
VAR2
FROM TABLE
WHERE {}
"""
```

I tried someting like this:

```
print(sql_code_arg2.format("VAR in "+tuple(list)))
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Which DB-API are you using ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using variables in the format() function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413109/using-variables-in-the-format-function-in-python)

Comment: It is for MS SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were trying to add a string with a tuple.

```
format("VAR in "+tuple(list)))
```

Rather, this should work:

```
sql_code_arg2.format("VAR in "+str(tuple(lst)))
```

**Disclaimer: This method is not recommended because it allows SQL injection**

Comment: Please do not recommend methods that allow SQL injection.

Comment: @Ijmc yes you are right!

Answer (score 0):

Avoid generating sql queries from raw string. its not flexible, unsafe and unmaintainable.
For generating sql queries use library https://github.com/kayak/pypika

With this library you can generate sql queries from objects like

```
customers = Table('customers')
q = Query.from_(customers).select(
    customers.id, customers.fname, customers.lname, customers.phone
).where(
    customers.fname == 'Max'
).where(
    customers.lname == 'Mustermann'
)
```

and when you need sql string you just cast query to string and get this

```
SELECT id,fname,lname,phone FROM customers WHERE fname='Max' AND lname='Mustermann'
```